# Getting list of files and folders on the user's computer with the filename filtered by the text line

Tags: c++, windows, file, indexing

Currently I'm developing a project that should do the thing described above on Windows. I have the idea to recurcively go through all user's drives and collect all information on then, but it seems to be really time consuming. So is there a better way to do such thing (maybe to use OS's index file or NTFS MFT)?

I use C++/Qt.

Comment: Do you mean filtering by filenames or filtering by contents? Your solution ideas suggest the former, but the title seems to indicate the latter.

Comment: @molbdnilo I mean filtering by filenames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for any of the many code examples for this and use one.

The library finctions which you use [FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa914391.aspx) and [FindNextFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa914380.aspx) are optimized and will go firectly to the FAT. They are coded by microsoft & I doubt that there is a faster way.

Btw, what do mean by "filtered by the text line"? Do you mean you want only filenames matching a certain pattern (use teh above) or files containing a string?

Comment: I mean filenames matching a one.

Comment: I think you mean that you want file names matching a string. So, use FindFirstFile and FindNextFile. The first parameter to FindFirstFile is "lpFileName

    [in] Pointer to a null-terminated string that specifies a valid directory or path and file name, which can contain wildcard characters, such as an asterisk (*) or a question mark (?)."

Comment: @gxoptg You will find a good code example here ... http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/93141/Iterative-Implementation-of-Recursively-Enumeratin  just chage the line ` StringCchCat(szDir, MAX_PATH, TEXT("\\*"));` to match your pattern